# Fragment declared target fragment that does not belong to this FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have made an activity A which has a fragment X in it. In fragment X, EditText item has on click event which opens fragment Y. This fragment displays a list of names. I press a name in the list, fragment Y closes and sends the selected name of to fragment X EditText. Here's the code I wrote:

```
YFragment y = new YFragment();
y.setTargetFragment(x.class, code);
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.frame, y)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

In fragment Y I have the code to send the data but the problem is in this block of code above. If I comment out the setTargetFragment line the code will work but no use as data will not be sent. If I run the app this error occurs:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment y{46d3d31 #3 id=0x7f090069}
>   declared target fragment x{e2c16 #0 id=0x7f090104
>   android:switcher:2131296516:0} that does not belong to this
>   FragmentManager!

Comment: your question saved me because h had the same problem and solved When using supportFragmentManager instead of  childFragmentManager

Answer (score 34):

To use `setTargetFragment()`, both the new `Fragment` and the target `Fragment` must be hosted within the same `FragmentManager`. The most common case where this would not happen is if you are using `Activity.getSupportFragmentManager()` or `Fragment.getFragmentManager()` alongside `Fragment.getChildFragmentManager()`.

Comment: how to make sure that my current fragment and the target fragment have same fragment manager ?

Comment: I checked by debugging and keeping breakpoint.. both of my FragmentManager's id is same still it crashes... So I am wondering...

Comment: Though might be bad practice, I changed my "getChildFragmentManager()" to "getFragmentManager", while it fixed the issue I could see this creating other issues in circumstances

Comment: @  C. Skjerdal any resolution to use other method? getFragmentManager is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

In my solution, replace

```
getChildFragmentManager()
```

with

```
Activity.getSupportFragmentManager() or Fragment.getFragmentManager()
```

that worked for me. Thank Mr.Ben P

Answer (score 2):

To new users where the "getFragmentManager" only work for it but don't want use deprecated method, the method "getParentFragmentManager" work too.

Comment: Above also not worked for me. I am using androidx latest