# Fragment declared target fragment that does not belong to this FragmentManager - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am using from `AppCompatDialogFragment` in my `DaggerFragment` but when run my app get bellow error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment CourseTypeListDialogFragment{ab0b7f3 (3d65d8c0-5c75-4b92-8002-1852a8aa58b7) } declared target fragment CoursesFragment{e2a5105 (e277e6f4-7e61-4114-8eb4-d0143a07ac0c) id=0x7f0800cc} that does not belong to this FragmentManager!
```

I opened it like bellow:

```
@OnClick(R.id.btnCourseType)
fun btnCourseTypeClick(){
    val fm = activity!!.supportFragmentManager
    val courseTypeListDialogFragment =
        CourseTypeListDialogFragment()
    courseTypeListDialogFragment.setCancelable(false)
    courseTypeListDialogFragment.setStyle(
        DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE,
        0
    )
    courseTypeListDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this@CoursesFragment, 1)
    courseTypeListDialogFragment.show(fm, "")

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045788/fragment-declared-target-fragment-that-does-not-belong-to-this-fragmentmanager/

Answer (score 0):

You did not add the fragment to the fragment manager

```
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.someFrame, courseTypeListDialogFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

only then you'll be able to use `show()`, `hide()` on this fragment

Answer (score 0):

I removed `courseTypeListDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this@CoursesFragment, 1)` and good work now.