# Declared target fragment that does not belong to this FragmentManager in androidx (Android studio java)

Tags: java, android, fragment, fragmentmanager, android-fragment-manager

I am trying to navigate from a fragment to another one fragment after the creation of post. It shows the Declared target fragment that does not belong to this FragmentManager. I have upgraded to androidx.fragment manager

```
 final FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        BaseFragment fragment = HomeFeed.newInstance(mValuesItem, CreatePost.this);
                        final String tag = BaseUtils.getTag(fragment);
                        transaction
                                .replace(getFragmentContainerId(), fragment, tag)
                                .addToBackStack(tag)
                                .commit();
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045788/fragment-declared-target-fragment-that-does-not-belong-to-this-fragmentmanager

Comment: Nothing worked for me